# Why column-oriented database is easier to scale?

Tags: database

I'm learning column-oriented database vs row-based. I understand it stores each columns rather than rows.

What I don't understand is why it's said to be easier to scale than row-based databases. In best case say we have 100 columns, we can scale them to 100 machines right? is that why it's easier to scale because we can shard the columns onto different machines? But I imagine the cross-shard query would also be painful in that case, isn't it?